# Angular - Enable button only if object inside an array contains completed:true

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter, angularjs-ng-disabled

I have an array that contains a bunch of objects.  If there are no objects that contains a "true" value for the key "completed", I would like to disable a button.

```
//Here is the format for the array of objects:

$scope.todos = [{
                task:$scope.task,
                completed: false,
                localID:Date.now(),
                display: true
}];

//Here is the button I want to disable::

<button ng-click="clear()" class="btn" ng-disabled="">Clear Completed</button>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could place filter over your `todos` object and check for there length.

**Markup**

```
<button ng-click="clear()" class="btn" ng-disabled="(todos | filter: {completed:true}).length < 1">
     Clear Completed
</button>
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3nxt66b6/)

Comment: much better than my solution .... but need to get it to work http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cp1ttr8t/5/

Comment: give me a one minute...i will figure it out

Comment: I have this:  but it is only working when everything is checked:

ng-disabled="(todos | filter: !{completed:false}).length > 0"

Comment: Why you added `!` in the filter `ng-disabled="(todos | filter: {completed:false}).length > 0"` to check any of the uncheck..

Comment: I want the button to be disabled by default, and only show if at least one item is checked.

Comment: @Triode that is contradict to you title headline,,please update that..i'll update my answer

Comment: I think I got it:

ng-disabled="(todos | filter: {completed:true}).length < 1"

Comment: @Triode sorry I didn't able to get a time to update answer..Now I did that..Thanks :) you could accept it..if you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can check something like

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {})

app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  $scope.todos = [{
    task: $scope.task,
    completed: false,
    localID: Date.now(),
    display: true
  }];

  $scope.isDisabled = function() {
    return $scope.todos.some(function(item) {
      return item.display === true
    })
  }


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="AppController">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todos[0].display" <br />
  <button ng-click="clear()" class="btn" ng-disabled="isDisabled()">Clear Completed</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ng-disabled="(todos | filter: {completed:true}).length < 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

html:

```
<button ng-click="clear()" class="btn" ng-disabled="isDisabled()">Clear Completed</button>
```

in controller:

```
$scope.isDisabled = function () {
        var disabled = true;
        angular.forEach($scope.todos, function(todo){
            if(todo.completed === true){
                disabled = false;
            }
        });
        return disabled;
    };
```

Comment: Working code in PLUNKER :


  http://plnkr.co/edit/xN9cE5wdywv7BTu6Gt2K?p=preview